# What do I need to get a valid NDA?

Tags: contract-law, non-compete

I've been hired to work on a website, and it's the first time that I'm leading a project. I usually only take care of the development part and I'm often asked to sign a non-disclosure agreement. I'm not sure how they work and I can see services online offering to write contracts but I don't know which one to choose, or if I should use one at all.

This contract has to be signed by the designer, and maybe the marketing team later. Some of the work will be done by freelancers living in foreign countries so I'm looking for a way to be covered worldwide. Here are my questions :

- Does a contract of this kind have to be validated by a legal authority?
- Where can I get assisted online to get a solid and valid contract that I could even use for my next similar projects?
- The contract should include a non-competition clause. Can I specify the length of the term?
- I see NDA samples online. Is it safe to write one myself by adapting one to my case?

Comment: You would be best to consult a lawyer as it can get really complex when involving multiple countries. What is enforceable in one would be laughed out of court in another.

Comment: @Terry Thank you for your reply. What about my 1st question? Do these contracts have to be validated by a legal authority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NDA is a contract, and at least in the U.S. a contract does not generally to be "validated" to be effective.  (There are probably still some foreign jurisdictions that require stamps or taxes be paid for certain contracts to be in force.)  In fact, in the U.S. a contract need not even be written to have legal force.

However, if you want your contract to actually accomplish specific business objectives you need to consult a lawyer to ensure that it will have the effects you desire in the jurisdictions you care about.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm just curious to know how verbal contracts work.

Comment: @user1319182 - The answer to that is, "Not very well if there is ever a disagreement."  [Here's a good Q&A on informal contracts](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/248/10).